# What is a bounded stochastic process?

Tags: probability

In the book of Karatzas and  Shreve (Brownian motion and stochastic calculs, 2nd edition) : lemma 2.4 page 132, they say :

> Let $X$ be a bounded, measurable, $\mathcal F_t$-adapted process. Thenthere exist a sequence $(X^{(m)})_m$ of simple process s.t. $$\sup_{T>0}\lim_{m\to \infty }\mathbb E\int_0^T|X_t^{(m)}-X_t|^2dt=0.$$

What quite confuse because they defined nowhere what they mean by $X$ is a bounded process. Does it mean that there is $M>0$ s.t. for all $t$ $$\mathbb P\{|X_t|\leq M\}=1 ?$$
or could it be $$\mathbb P\{\forall t, |X_t|\leq M\}=1 ?$$
Or maybe $\forall \omega \in \Omega $ there is $M(\omega )$ s.t. $|X_t(\omega )|\leq M(\omega )$ ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it means that there is some constant $c$ such that the value $X_t$ can never exceed it, i.e. $X_t\leq c$, but I'll let more knowledgeable folks weigh in.

Comment: Does the constant depend on $t$ or not ? (as you wrote, there is still a big doubt). @Mars

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on $t$.  Otherwise $c$ could increase with $t$, and the entire process might be unbounded, i.e. for any constant, it could eventually exceed it.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $\mathbb P(\sup_t |X_t|>M)=0$, for some $M>0$. Note that this condition is used in the proof of the lemma in order to apply the [bounded convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem) several times.

Comment: Isn't it equivalent to $\mathbb P\{\forall t, |X_t|\leq M\}=1$ for a certain $M>0$ ?

Comment: Yes the two conditions are equivalent, since $|X_t(\omega)|\leq M$ for all $t$ if and only if $\sup |X_t|\leq M$.